# Changing colors on google material bar chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am using google's new [Material Bar Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Material) to display a graph with a `chart.title` and `chart.subtitle` option but am not able to change the colors. What I am trying to achive is

http://jsfiddle.net/8pjuz38c/1/

But the closest thing I get is:

http://jsfiddle.net/8pjuz38c/5/

Why aren't the colors applied to the series?

Comment: Probably a bug or they still haven´t made that available for material charts, maybe @asgallant has some insight

Comment: Trying to solve the same problem--have you had any luck?

Comment: Nope, no luck so far, let me know if you come across a solution.

Comment: The page mentions that their Material Design bar chart is used to "support a common look and feel across its properties", so I think they are forcing their palette color choices.

Comment: I don't understand what you wanted to do at all. if jsfiddle #1 works why you need jsfiddle #5 ? If you just want to select the color see my update at jsfiddle #47

Comment: here is the answer for this issue https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2007

Answer (score 4):

### Material barchart vs. barchart

You are confusing a 'material barchart' with a normal 'barchart'. The method you used for coloring the bars is the method to use for the normal barchart. Not the material one.

## The difference

Compare the lines of codes underneath.

**Normal barchart**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

and

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

**Material barchart**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
```

and

```
 var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

### Previous answer (relates to a material bar chart with mulitipe bars per item)

Add the colors attribute to the option object.

**Example:**

```
var options = {
        title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
        colors: ['#b0120a', '#ffab91']
      };
```

So the code in de jsFiddel as shown above should be:

It's working for me in je jsFiddle. Make sure your code is like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarColors);

function drawBarColors() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
        ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
        ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
        ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
        ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
        ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000]
      ]);

      console.log(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable);

      var options = {
        title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        colors: ['#b0120a', '#ffab91'],
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Total Population',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'City'
        }
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: Adding: 
        var options = {
    colors: ['#00ff0a', '#44abff'],......  worked for me.

Comment: here is the answer for this issue https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2007

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, in this case I think is a bug related with `isStacked` option, if this option is set to `true` the material bar chart will take the colour palette as a gradient from the first element of the array.

But if you set that option to false, you will have access to all the array of colours. But the data will not be stacked.
`colors: ['#b0120a', '#ffab91']`.

Comment: well as I mentioned before, it was a bug my code fixed itself

Comment: here is the answer for this issue https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2007